# Maximum call stack size exceeded when trying to assign value to the same property inside accessor set

Tags: javascript, accessor

The following object uses the set birthdate accesor to set the user's age, it works properly.

```js
const user = {
  set birthdate(value) {
    if (isNaN(Date.parse(value))) {
      throw new Error("Invalid date format");
    }

    const valueYear = new Date(value).getFullYear();
    const todayYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    const age = todayYear - valueYear;

    if (age < 18) {
      throw new Error("Invalid user age");
    }

    this.age = age;
  },
};

user.birthdate = "1980-01-29";

console.log(user.age);
```

Now I need to get the birthdate, but when I try `this.birthdate = new Date(value);` inside the set accessor I get `InternalError: too much recursion` error message

```js
const user = {
  set birthdate(value) {
    if (isNaN(Date.parse(value))) {
      throw new Error("Invalid date format");
    }

    const valueYear = new Date(value).getFullYear();
    const todayYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    const age = todayYear - valueYear;

    if (age < 18) {
      throw new Error("Invalid user age");
    }

    this.birthdate = new Date(value); // when adding this line the error occurs
    this.age = age;
  },
};

user.birthdate = "1980-01-29";

console.log(user.age);
```

What is the correct way to have a property in the object that gets the value set in birthdate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is that you have defined a setter for `birthdate` property, so any attempt to set a value of `birthdate` property will result in calling the setter function. Since your are setting `this.birthdate` inside the setter function, this function is called recursively again and again.

You need to use a different property name to store birth date

```js
const user = {
  set birthdate(value) {
    if (isNaN(Date.parse(value))) {
      throw new Error("Invalid date format");
    }

    const valueYear = new Date(value).getFullYear();
    const todayYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    const age = todayYear - valueYear;

    if (age < 18) {
      throw new Error("Invalid user age");
    }

    this.bDate = new Date(value);
    this.age = age;
  },
};

user.birthdate = "1980-01-29";

console.log(user.age);
console.log(user.bDate.toDateString());
```

Comment: very well explained, it makes perfect sense, thanks

Comment: I have only modified it as follows `this._birthdate = new Date(value);` and to get birthdate using the same property name I have used a get `get birthdate() { return this._birthdate; }`